# Sum total amount per product per date and bind it to a gridview programatically WPF & LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, gridview, binding

The scenario:
I need to essentially build a gridview from code that will have binding set for each column while my data consists of amount of each product that manufactured each day (between specific dates but I got that covered).

The Problem:
I know how to bind through XAML with a class that has specific properties but this thing will be dynamic, since I don't know what products were manufactured in these specific dates and there is no guarantee that all of them were. so I need to build a dynamic (thought about ObservableCollection) option that will let me add items with their binding to my simple class inside an ObservableCollection (or whatever you think is best for this).

Current code:
This is the simple class I use to have the products and the amounts and that should be for each date:

```
        public class MonthlyProducts
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Now this is how I know which products were indeed manufactured:

```
    var ProductsInDates =
                    from Production in context.production
                    where Production.ProductionDate >= dtpStartDate.SelectedDate && Production.ProductionDate <= dtpEndDate.SelectedDate
                    group Production by Production.ProductID into Products
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = Products.Key
                    };
```

This is how I build the table, and here is where I'm not sure about how to bind the data through code:

```
    foreach (var item in ProductsInDates)
            {
                MonthlyProducts temp = new MonthlyProducts();
                temp.ProductID = item.ID;
                temp.Amount = 0;
                MonthObservable.Add(temp);
                GridViewColumn TempColumn = new GridViewColumn();
                TempColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(temp.ProductID);
                TempColumn.Header = temp.ProductID;
                TempColumn.Width = 100;
                MonthlyGridView.Columns.Add(TempColumn);
            }
```

Now comes the hard part, This is where I get all the Amounts of the products that were manufactured (or shell I say not getting it yet since I don't know how to do it):

```
    var MonthProduction =
                    from Production in context.production
                    where Production.ProductionDate >= dtpStartDate.SelectedDate && Production.ProductionDate <= dtpEndDate.SelectedDate
                    group Production by Production.ProductionDate into MonthlyReport
                    select new
                    {
                        DateID = MonthlyReport.Key,
                        Row = MonthlyReport
                    };
```

This is just me trying to play with this.

Basically I need to know if the Binding I did above to the data column will work since I can't check it yet, and I need to know how to sum each product for each date in this last LINQ query.

I hope I didn't forget anything, if so let me know and I'll provide all the info needed.

Comment: you can bind anonymous data with grid. you just need to create collection of your multiple objects.

Comment: ok but how can I do that? I don't know anything about anonymous data other then var. if you could point me to something or post a code here that will help a lot.